# Fetch data from mysql into JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I am using the following PHP code to fetch some data from my database. It contains chats and messages between users in those chats. I want to return the information of both users plus the messages they exchanged. My test data has two chats with ID's 1 and 2. There are two messages, both in chat 1, however for some reason they are returned for both chats 1 and 2. I'm not sure what the problem in my code is.

```
 $response = array();


 $myArray = array();
while($row = $user_chats->fetch_array())
{
 $myArray["chatId"] = $row["chat_id"];
 $myArray["user1_id"] = $row["user1"];
 $myArray["user2_id"] = $row["user2"];
 $myArray["user1_name"] = $user1_name;
 $myArray["user2_name"] = $user2_name;
 $myArray["user1_profile_pic"] = $result_user1["profile_pic"];
 $myArray["user2_profile_pic"] = $result_user2["profile_pic"];
 $messages = array();
 $chat_idd = $row["chat_id"];
 $chat_messages = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatID = '$chat_idd' ORDER BY timestamp ASC");
 $count = 1;
 while($roww = $chat_messages->fetch_array()) {
 if ($row["chat_id"] == $roww["chatID"]) {
 $messages["message_id"] = $roww["message_id"];
 $messages["sender"] = $roww["sender"];
 $messages["chatId"] = $roww["chatID"];
 $messages["text"] = $roww["text"];
 $messages["timestamp"] = $roww["timestamp"];
 $myArray["message"][$count] = $messages;
 $count = $count + 1;
 }
 else {
 $myArray["message"]= 0;

 }
 }
 $response[] = $myArray;

}
echo json_encode($response);
```

produces the following response:

```html
[{"chatId":"1","user1_id":"32132132","user2_id":"2121","user1_name":"dwqd",
"user2_name":"dqdwdw","user1_profile_pic":"http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/dwqwqdqdwdw\/picture?type=large","user2_profile_pic":"WDQdwqwqddqwdqwdq","message":{"1":{"message_id":"24242241","sender":"32132132","chatId":"1","text":"hello i am",
"timestamp":"2016-05-24 17:13:08"},"2":{"message_id":"421421","sender":"32132132",
"chatId":"1","text":"great","timestamp":"2016-05-24 17:15:08"}}},{"chatId":"2","user1_id":"23413524635","user2_id":"32132132","user1_name":false,
"user2_name":"dwqd","user1_profile_pic":
WDQdwqwqddqwdqwdq" ,"user2_profile_pic":"http:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/32132132\/picture?type=large",
"message":{"1":{"message_id":"24242241","sender":"32132132","chatId":"1","text":"hello i am",
"timestamp":"2016-05-24 17:13:08"},"2":{"message_id":"421421","sender":"32132132","chatId":"1",
"text":"great","timestamp":"2016-05-24 17:15:08"}}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize $myArray at each iteration through the loop, e.g.

`while($row = $user_chats->fetch_array()) {
   $myArray = array();`